# A long, straight, stiff mudguard?

Tags: commuter, fenders, rain

I saw a bike with such a mudguard the other day. It was mounted on the seat tube and stuck straight out horizontally, between the two seat stays, over the brake and then over the rear wheel.

I liked the mount point because it means that the top of the seat tube is protected from crud, unlike seat post mounted mudguards.

Does anyone know where I can buy such a mudguard? Or who makes one like it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think of three kind of mud guards that fit the description: [musguard](http://www.designboom.com/design/musguard-rollable-bike-fender/), [quickfix](http://www.gizmag.com/quickfix-foldnfix-bicycle-mudguards/20348/), and [fender bender](http://velolifestyle.com/fenders/wit).

An other solution is the **ass saver**, but this is not what you are looking for.

Comment: the [fender bender](http://velolifestyle.com/fenders/wit)

Comment: Added that link to the post for you. Welcome to bikes.se!

Comment: I'v seen it, thx :)

Answer (score 1):

I've just spent some time looking online and found quite a few results on Amazon, Ebay, (you could also try wiggle, which is kind of like an online surplus shop.) unfortunately without seeing a picture of exactly what you saw, I can only paint a vague picture of what you're talking about. But any of those websites would be a good starting point.

And, just to throw the idea out there, considering the kind of basic function that this thing does, you could also research any DIY projects people have done where they made their own mudguards out of stuff they already had. It might look weird,  it if you put your time into it you could make something practical and easy on the eyes.